# static content deploy command autometically killed

Tags: magento2.3.2, static-content-deploy

I am running command setup:static-content:deploy -f its running for while, but after sometime it got killed in magento2.3.2. Please let me know the exact issue for this.

Comment: is it incomplete? or any error you are getting?

Comment: try -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: please share error details.

Comment: I run deploy command.it does execution,after some time it got killed,

Answer (score 3):

Please try below command

```
php bin/magento  c:c

php bin/magento  setup:upgrade

php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope it works!

Comment: You save my day! Thanks :) 
`php -d memory_limit=5G` was the key for me.

Comment: @hayatbiralem thanks mate